# What are conditions in order for multiple batches to work well in TensorFlow Lite?

Tags: tensorflow-lite

You know, TensorFlow Lite works well for multiple batches of inference by calling ResizeInputTensor before inference in some cases.
But my model does not work well.

What are conditions in order for multiple batches to work well in TensorFlow Lite?

I suspect that you need to set batch dimension to -1 for Reshape.

I would like to know precise conditions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to have dynamic batch, the original model must have dynamic batch and then when you convert to tflite, the exported model will support resizing batch.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Nosseir san. I tried it at first and failed. It may be due to platform issue. My target is Kirin 990, not popular Snapdragon series. When you convert a model with variable batch size, the result includes operations which NNAPI for Kirin series does not support.

Comment: Currently NNAPI delegate doesn't support dynamic sized tensors. But you can run it on CPU with dynamic batch support.
If you want to use NNAPI, you can make the input shape static pre conversion and re convert the model

Comment: Yes, and your last statement is exactly my question. I had succeeded multiple batches on NNAPI when converting TensorFlow 1, but TensorFlow 2 or 2.4.0 and later, TF converts variable batch models in complex way. I want to know the conditions of models to work well for multiple batches on NNAPI.